# Export and changing javascript object from es6 module with webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Export and changing javascript object from es6 module with webpack.

If I change config's property in index.js, it changes, but it's not impossible to use Object.assign.
My code describes a problem better.
Example is simplidied

config.js

```
let config = {
    plugins: {
        slick: {
            autoplaySpeed: 1000,
            autoplay: true,
        }
    }
};
export default config;
```

index.js

```
import config from './config.js'
config.plugins.slick.autoplaySpeed = 500;
import './clientCode';
```

clientCode.js

```
import config from './config';

//autoplaySpeed: 500, as it need to be
console.dir(config.plugins.slick);  
//autoplaySpeed: 1000, needs to be 500, ->why<- value not changed?
console.dir(Object.assign({}, config.plugins.slick));
```

Why value not changed after Object.assign but changed before Object.assign?

But if I assign value to exported config directly in clientCode.js file, then value changes after Object.assign.

clientCode.js

```
import config from './config';
config.plugins.slick.autoplaySpeed = 500;//new value assigning

//autoplaySpeed: 500, as it need to be
console.dir(config.plugins.slick)
//autoplaySpeed: 500, as it need to be
console.dir(Object.assign({}, config.plugins.slick));
```

I've tried to restart my webpack watcher (think that problem is in webpack's cache),
but this wasn't solved the problem.

How can I change config's values in one file, and use changed values in another with Object.assign?
Why this problem appears?

Update:
Now I've understood that problem is in ordering of these files execution.
console.dir in clientCode.js executes before than other one in index.js

Now digging in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with this way of module import.

index.js

```
import config from './config.js'
config.plugins.slick.autoplaySpeed = 500;
import init from './clientCode';
init();
```

clientCode.js

```
import config from './config';
export default function init(){
    //autoplaySpeed: 500, as it need to be
    console.dir(config.plugins.slick);  
    //autoplaySpeed: 500, 500, as it need to be
    console.dir(Object.assign({}, config.plugins.slick)); 
}
```